# Как рандомизировать числа чтобы при большом числе итераций они не повторялись?

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

У меня работает бот, отправляющий большое количество запросов к сайту с параметром, который должен быть уникален при каждом запросе.

Сначала я пробовал присваивать ему значение `time.time()*1000`, но иногда запросы посылались одновременно. Потом я пробовал присвоить `random.uniform(0, 10^8)`, но и в таком случае иногда бот падает.

Какой есть эффективный способ генерации числа так, чтобы оно не повторилось?

Comment: «в таком случае иногда бот падает» — почему падает?

Comment: Если запросов НАСТОЛЬКО много, что даже 64-битные числа с плавающей точкой начинают повторяться, то единственный разумный способ решить проблему — помнить абсолютно все созданные числа и при генерации проверять, что это число ещё не выпадало ранее

Comment: падает потому что число при запросе совпало

Comment: Тогда только или запоминать, или генерировать по порядку, а не случайно

Comment: а по порядку каким образом?

Comment: n = n + 1, каким же ещё

Comment: если нужно int, то попробуйте time.time()*1000000

Comment: Вы запускаете бота на одной машине, или на нескольких? Если на одной, то в python есть библиотека `multiprocessing` c поддержкой [общих переменных](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects). Если на разных, то для них можно поднять какой-нибудь тривиальный веб-сервер, который будет выдавать на любой запрос монотонно растущее число.

Answer (score 4):

Для получения случайного глобального уникального идентификатора можно воспользоваться стандартным модулем [uuid](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/uuid.html):

```
In [8]: from uuid import uuid1, uuid3, uuid4, uuid5

In [9]: uuid4()
Out[9]: UUID('f2feff6a-df8e-43aa-bcd1-9ad0ababdd22')

In [10]: uuid4().int
Out[10]: 172456381865547334548545134784325968087

In [11]: uuid4().hex
Out[11]: 'b7d0c276460840c189ebf37e02fb97e9'

In [12]: uuid4().urn
Out[12]: 'urn:uuid:ca140af2-761c-4f41-9ac6-837b6c5d437e'
```

Comment: uuid не гарантирует уникальность, особенно uuid4.

Comment: и число должно быть int

Comment: @andreymal, `If all you want is a unique ID, you should probably call uuid1() or uuid4(). Note that uuid1() may compromise privacy since it creates a UUID containing the computer’s network address. uuid4() creates a random UUID.` - думаете врут?

Comment: @Vlad, `uuid4().int` ??

Comment: @MaxU врут. Вероятность совпадения в обозримом будущем крайне мала, но она всё равно есть в обоих случаях. У uuid1 ограниченная точность метки времени, а uuid4 абсолютно точно станет совпадать, если сгенерировать его 2¹²²+1 раз ;)

Comment: @andreymal, по-моему там речь идет о 2^128 уникальных числах. И если генерировать по триллиону чисел в секунду, то понадобится всего-то 10790283 триллионов лет ;)

Comment: @MaxU 4 бита отводятся под версию, 2 бита под вариант 1, к оставшимся 122 битам применяем [атаку «дней рождения»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%C2%AB%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%C2%BB) и получаем, что дубликаты uuid4 на практике попрут всего лишь через месяц :P